# Providing native app updates and support mechanism

Tags: android, ios

I am new to native app development just want to know the current best practices being followed by the mobile companies to support the apps created by them.
For e.g if user A uses an App and faces a problem what all support strategies App development company should take care to provide easy debugging and release the new updates of the app with the notification to the user A.

Any links on this will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Sajesh Nambiar

Comment: JSConsole is one approach which is used for remote debugging,similarly is there any other thing

Comment: Experts need your valuable inputs